# Continuous pagination with multiple pages having no page number

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a long document (~450 pages) in which most pages should show the page number, but I have about 20 pages distributed among the document which are title pages and I want them to have **no** page number.

So far, I **cannot** find a way to accomplish this.

If the title pages are their own section, I can arrange for them not to have a page number, but then the subsequent pagination starts at 1, instead of whatever it was in the document.

If the title pages are **not** their own section, they keep the header style of the previous section and get a page number (which I don't want).

If I manually set the starting page number for each page in sections following the title sections, I lose auto-numbering and it's impossibly tedious to maintain the numbers among dozens of sections as the page counts constantly change.

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: If you have an ordinary page 10, followed by a Title page, followed by another ordinary page, do you want the second ordinary page to be numbered 11 or 12? *If* you have a ToC that lists the title pages, do you want a page number in it, and what should it be for this title page?

Answer (score 0):

In your footer, you can use calculation for page number with the = FIELD instead of just the PAGE field.  You just need a counter that you include on each cover page - for example (if your cover pages aren't already numbered with a style), create a SEQ field and apply a paragraph style to it (probably as hidden text and only applied to the SEQ field).

Then in your footer instead of page number it would be an = FIELD for PAGE field - STYLEREF field.

Each time you insert a new section, use different first page option for section so you can omit page number from cover pages.  Add your SEQ field paragraph to it, then select all and update all fields so the sequence number is correct.  If you have link to previous for footers, your calculation field will carry through so you don't need to set it up each time.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want the Title Pages to count in the numbering but not display a page number (the usual arrangement). This way items in your Table of Contents and Index that relate to things on those pages will have appropriate page numbers even though one is not shown on the page.

If so have each Title Page begin a new section. The page break should likely be an odd-page section break. If not, use a Next-Page section break.
Set your Headers and Footers to "Different First Page."

The page numbers should not appear.
The page number on the next page should reflect the existence of the title page in the numbering sequence. I.e., if the title page is the 31st page in the document numbering, even though unnumbered, the following page should be numbered 32.

The title pages are not their own sections but are the first page of a section that includes the following pages, up until the next section. Thus, different headers/footers for the "first page."

*Note that it is unusual to not use link-to-previous in a book header/footer.* You can use the **StyleRef** field to put content in headers and footers that relates only to that section. The content of that field in the header/footer will change as you go through the document.

Comment: Is this what you needed?